# How to create a function with vectors and vertical asymptote using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, vector

Plot the function f(x) = 1.5x / x-4 for -10 equal or less than X equal or less than 10. Notice that the function have a vertical asymptote at x = 4. Plot the function by creating two vectors for the domain of x. The first vector (call it x1) with elements from -10 to 3.7, and the second vector (calle it x2) with elements from 4.3 to 10. For each of the X vector create a Y  vector (call them y1 and y2) with the corresponding values of Y according to the function. To plot the function make two curves in the same plot (y1 vs. x1 and y2 vs. x2).

Comment: If you copy-paste homework, at least label the question as such. Also, could you tell us how far you have come by yourself?

Comment: I think is creating a M-file. And yes is a stupid hw, and I dont know how to do it, that is why I am asking the " experts" how to solve this problem using MATLAB. If somebody knows what do I writte in the command window or in the editor in matlab, let me know, I will appreciate thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Learn how to create vectors in Matlab. First look at the [colon(:) operator](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/colon.shtml), which creates vectors, if you know start, step and end values. Look also at [LINSPACE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/linspace.html) function, if you don't need to know how far the points in a vector are, but how many points do you need. It will help you to create vectors x1 and x2.

Then learn how to do [arithmetic calculations](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) in MATLAB. Create vectors y1 and y2.

Then create the plot with [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) function. You may need to use [HOLD ON, HOLD OFF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html) to draw two curves on the same figure.